# Facebook post liker search javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, web

I have a javascript code but it is incomplete. I want to search a specific person who liked some facebook post. for example, in any post, if I click on "likes" button it will show the list of people who liked that post. It will show 10 people and then at the botton is written "see more". I want to have a javascript code that will get "person name" from keyboard and compare it with the list who liked the post and if it approaches at bottom, it should autoclick on "see more" to enhance the list for more people search until there is no person left or until the person found.

That javascript code is to be injected in consol of firefox/opera/googleCrhome browsers etc...

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButton _1sm');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
 inputs[i].click();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by **injected in consol of firefox/opera/googleCrhome browsers** ?

Comment: you will need to declare a string which will contain the  name that you want to search in the list. for example: name = "joseph"

Comment: inject mean when i open facebook post and click on the "likes" button to preview the list of people who liked the post. I will then right click on page and select "Inspectt Element". A portion of that will open and I select the tab "console" and paste the javascript code in it and then  run.

Comment: facebook has protection against xss

Comment: @madalinivascu im not agreed. There are lot of jscripts you can find on internet such as "auto friend request accept", "auto like", "auto mention" etc.. which are used to inject from console of browser to the facebook using an fb ID. its normal

Comment: those are all illegal. don´t do stupid stuff like that, it is not "normal".

Comment: This will be greatly helpful to me because in my requirements, I need to search for specific people in the list of thousands of likers. I cannot use the search option CTRL+F of the browser because list shows just first 10 people and I will have to expand it +10 more.

Comment: what for exactly do you need to know the information? and why not just use the graph api? that would be the proper (and only allowed) way. scraping is not allowed on facebook.

Comment: graph api is not useful. it has minimum features

Comment: it has everything you need. if there is no way with the graph api, it´s most likely not allowed. again, what for do you need to know the information?